# Json_encode correct format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I made this code:

```
$jsonpost = array();
     while ($query_news->have_posts()) : $query_news->the_post();
           $jsonpost[] = array("tags"=> array(      
                'name' => 'name',
                'content' => ''
            )); 
 endwhile; 
 echo json_encode($jsonpost);
```

The get a json feed.
This gives the following result

```
[
{
    "tags": {
        "name": "tes",
        "content": "test"
    }
},
{
    "tags": {
        "name": "test",
        "content": "test"
    }
}
]
```

But i want the following result, with extra [], but i don't know how to add this:

```
[
{
    "tags": [{
        "name": "tes",
        "content": "test"
    }]
},
{
    "tags": [{
        "name": "test",
        "content": "test"
    }]
}
]
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What are the extra `[ ]` in JSON? - Add that to your code

Comment: Out of curiosity... Why would you want it?

Comment: You see the differents in the example. I want this because the script where i'm working with need this type of json to read it. I don't know how to add this to the array here.

Comment: You are missing one level of a numeric array. You are casting the "tags" as an assoc array when you want it to be an empty numeric array that gets filled with an assoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code to wrap your [array in an array](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/63481848.jpg).

```
$jsonpost[] = array("tags"=> array( array(      
                'name' => 'name',
                'content' => ''
            ))); 

 echo json_encode($jsonpost);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (I havent tested it).

```
$jsonpost = array();
while ($query_news->have_posts()) :
        $query_news->the_post();
        $row    =   [];         //create empty array
        $row[]  =   [           //add the assoc array to that array (this makes it numeric)
                        'name' => 'name',
                        'content' => ''
                        ];
        $jsonpost[] = [ "tags"=> $row]; 
endwhile; 
echo json_encode($jsonpost);
```

The difference in the array structur is visible in the array structure;

Incorrect:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tags] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => tes
                    [content] => test
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tags] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => test
                    [content] => test
                )

        )

)
```

Outpus:
[{"tags":{"name":"tes","content":"test"}},{"tags":{"name":"test","content":"test"}}]

Correct:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => tes
                            [content] => test
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => test
                            [content] => test
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Outputs:
[{"tags":[{"name":"tes","content":"test"}]},{"tags":[{"name":"test","content":"test"}]}]